# What is window.localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

The [`option.js`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/examples/extensions/email_this_page/options.js) file of ["**Email this page**"](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html#028eb5364924344029bcbe1d527f132fc72b34e5) (Chrome extension example) contains the following code:

```
if (window.localStorage == null) {
  ...
if (window.localStorage.customMailtoUrl == null) {
```

What does this mean? What is `window.localStorage`?

Comment: http://appdeveloper.intel.com/en-us/article/using-html5-local-storage-your-web-apps

Comment: @AndyRay "_let me google it for you_", i suspect.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/local-storage/info

Comment: @c69 I want you to think very carefully about what you just did, and then give yourself a time out.

Comment: what o_O ? you asked - i answered: "_what is lmgtfy? – @AndyRay 1 hour ago_"

Comment: Calm down, folks. "LMGTFY" links are not acceptable on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

localStorage/sessionStorage is part of HTML5 API. Essentially, this is what cookies are used for. But this is a lot better.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

Comment: localStorage is actually very different from cookie. Values aren't send to the server, they don't have built-in expiration, etc.. localStorage is not a better tool, it's a different tool.

Comment: @HoLyVieR so what ? expiration is often misused anyway, and sending cookies to server with every request is very inefficient.

Comment: @c69 Well sending cookie for every HTTP request is what your browser do and that's what the specification of cookie says. That's what cookie are by-design. I'm not sure if you understand what cookies are. You don't have the choice to send or not to send cookies to the server.

Comment: @HoLyVieR cookies were created by Netscape to implement shopping cart. This is what they are "by-design". A "web-app state management mechanism", but even the spec calls cookies "[HTTP State Management Mechanism](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265)", and that's by far not what most developers need. Expiration date is useless, and sending cookies with each request is redundant for every other type of cookie that is not http-only auth, session or tracking cookie.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp:

"What is HTML Local Storage?

With local storage, web applications can store data locally within the user's browser.

Before HTML5, application data had to be stored in cookies, included in every server request. Local storage is more secure, and large amounts of data can be stored locally, without affecting website performance.

Unlike cookies, the storage limit is far larger (at least 5MB) and information is never transferred to the server.

Local storage is per domain. All pages, from one domain, can store and access the same data."

Answer (score 0):

**localStorage** is a property of HTML5 API which allows web applications to store data locally within the user's browser.

Before HTML5, application data had to be stored in cookies, included in every server request. localStorage is a different property which has many advantages over cookies.

**HTML local storage provides two objects for storing data on the client:**

**window.localStorage** - stores data with no expiration date

**window.sessionStorage** - stores data for one session (data is lost when the browser tab is closed)

**localStorage features:**

- The localStorage data has no expiration date.
- localStorage is more secure since it doesn't send anything to server, everything happens at client side i.e. browser.
- localStorage is per origin means two or more html pages, from one origin, can store and access the same data stored in localStorage Object.
- It can store much more data than cookies. The storage size varies for each browser for example the latest versions of chrome & firefox can store atleast 5MB of data.